# Understanding the proof of the Concentration-Compactness principle

Tags: proof-explanation, partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, smooth-functions

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
I'm reading parts of the paper [*The Concentration-Compactness Principle in the Calculus of Variations. The Limit Case, Part 1*](http://dmle.icmat.es/pdf/MATEMATICAIBEROAMERICANA_1985_01_01_07.pdf) by P.L. Lions. I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 1.1, but I'm having some trouble. The hypotheses of the lemma are the following:

> Let $(u_n)_n$ be a bounded sequence in $W^{m,p}_0(\R^N)$ converging weakly to some $u$ and such that $|D^m u_n|^p$ converges weakly to $\mu$, and $|u_n|^p$ converges tightly to $\nu$, where $\mu,\nu$ are bounded nonnegative measures on $\R^N$.

The proof (p.160, or p.16 in the PDF) starts off by letting $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(\R^N)$ and applying Sobolev's inequality to $\phi u_n$:

\begin{align*}
\left(
\int \limits_{\R^N} |\phi|^q |u_n|^q dx
\right)^{1/q}
\leq C
\left(
\int \limits_{\R^N} |D^m(\phi u_n)|^p dx
\right)^{1/p}
\end{align*}

Then, there is the following argument:

> The right-hand side is estimated as follows:
>
> $$
> \left|
> \left(
> \int_{\R^N} |D^m(\phi u_n)|^p dx
> \right)^{1/p}
> -
> \left(
> \int_{\R^N} |\phi|^p |D^m u_n|^p
> \right)^{1/p}
> \right|
> \\
> \leq
> C \sum \limits_{j=0}^{m-1}
> \left(
> \int_{\R^N} |D^{m-j}\phi|^p |D^j u_n|^p dx
> \right)^{1/p}
> $$
>   And using the fact that $\phi$ has compact support and the Rellich theorem, we see that this bound goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

**Questions:**

1. Where does the estimate come from? I tried to expand the derivative of the product $\phi u_n$, but it didn't get me anywhere.
2. How do we conclude that bound goes to $0$? I know the Rellich theorem is about compact embeddings of $W^{1,p}$ into $L^r$ for appropriate values of $r$, but I don't see how it helps. Is there a version for the general space $W^{m,p}$?

A final point: the paper defines $|D^m \phi(x)|$ as "any product norm of all derivatives of order $m$ at the point $x$". Is this different from the definition in Evans' book, i.e. $|D^m \phi| = (\sum_{|\alpha|=m} |D^{\alpha} \phi|^2)^{1/2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Expanding was the correct idea. Note that we have by the product rule $$D^m (\phi un) = \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j} D^{m-j} \phi \, D^j u_n,$$ thus we can cancel the $m$-th term in the sum using the reverse triangle inequality $$\begin{aligned} \big| \|D^m(\phi u_n) \|_{L^p} - \|\phi D^m u_n \|_{L^p} \big|\leq \|D^m(\phi u_n)-\phi D^m u_n\|_{L^p} \leq C\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \|D^{m-j} \phi \, D^j u_n\|_{L^p}.\end{aligned}$$
2. Yes, there is such a version of Rellich's theorem. Indeed, $W_0^{m,p}$ is compactly embedded in $W_0^{m-1,p}$ for a bounded domain. Now, since we cancelled the $m$-th sum in the estimate, we can directly apply Rellich. See the book "Linear Functional Analysis" by H.W. Alt.
3. Indeed, it is defined in the same way.

Comment: I have a couple questions. First, shouldn't there be binomial coefficients in the expansion of the derivative? I guess this is where the constant comes from. Second, how do we justify the inequality? We have $a\leq b$, but this doesn't let us say $|a-c|\leq |b-c|$

Comment: @Sambo True, but you can make use of the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: I don't follow. How do you justify the inequality which gives the summation?

Comment: @Sambo That is the normal triangle inequality, $\| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|a_i\|$. Before that, we can insert the derivative with an equality(!) and cancel the $m$-th derivative.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I wasn't thinking properly